# redirecting domain to index.php via php script

Tags: php, redirect, indexing

I can't manage to make my site being automatically redirected to my index.php file from my domain, that is, I can't:
www.mysite.com ==> www.mysite.com/index.php  when I enter www.mysite.com

I can't edit any .htacces or similar configuration file, cause my site is Hosted on a hosting service provider which doesn't allow me to edit such files.
Do I have a way with some php script, to be able to redirect my main domain to index.php ?
Thks
M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to edit your .htaccess, you could use this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/index.php [L,R=301]
```

But if you aren't, then you could add this in your `index.html` file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=http://www.mysite.com/index.php">
```

This is an acceptable solution and works just fine but it's certainly not the *best* solution.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `index.html` page from your site and add `index.php` page then,

It will redirect to `www.mysite.com/index.php`